# Extract words from list of lists and store them in a separate variable in python

Tags: python, list, variables

I have this list of lists and I would like to extract each word from the list and store them in a separate variable

```
keywords=[[('tarifa',), ('mantenimiento',), ('mensual',)],
[('tasa',), ('anual',)],
[('tasa',)],
[('int ',)],
[('comision',)],
[('seguro',), ('bancaria',)],
[('seguro',), ('generales',)],
[('mi salud',), ('unific',)]]
```

So for each list you should have kw variables, for example for the first list:
kw1='tarifa' kw2='mantenimiento' kw3 = 'mensual'
For the second list
kw1='tasa' kw2='anual'
and so on

I have this code:

```
for i in range(len(keywords)):
    for j in range(len(keywords[i])):
        print("'"+keywords[i][j][0]+"'",end=",")
    print()
```

but it only returns this:

```
'tarifa','mantenimiento','mensual',
'tasa','anual',
'tasa',
'int ',
'comision',
'seguro','bancaria',
'seguro','generales',
'mi salud','unific',
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean store them in a separate variable. You can use python dictionaries to associate a value with a key (or variable).
Here's an example where we extract each  list of tuples and convert to dictionary with key starting with 'kw' followed by its index and associated tuple as value.
Hope this helps.

```
>>> l = [[('tarifa',), ('mantenimiento',), ('mensual',)],
... [('tasa',), ('anual',)],
... [('tasa',)],
... [('int ',)],
... [('comision',)],
... [('seguro',), ('bancaria',)],
... [('seguro',), ('generales',)],
... [('mi salud',), ('unific',)]]
>>> z = []
>>> for x in l:
...   y = [item[0] for item in x]
...   z.append({f'kw{i}':v for i,v in enumerate(y)})
... 
>>> z
[{'kw0': 'mi salud', 'kw1': 'unific'}, {'kw0': 'mi salud', 'kw1': 'unific'}, {'kw0': 'mi salud', 'kw1': 'unific'}, {'kw0': 'mi salud', 'kw1': 'unific'}, {'kw0': 'mi salud', 'kw1': 'unific'}, {'kw0': 'mi salud', 'kw1': 'unific'}, {'kw0': 'mi salud', 'kw1': 'unific'}, {'kw0': 'mi salud', 'kw1': 'unific'}]
>>>
```

**Update:**

Based on discussion.
You dont need to convert list of tuples to variables. Simply convert to list of strings and iterate through each to match string from list to text from dataframe.
Here's sample text that contains some of your words from list of lists.

```
sents =
['Lorem tarifa ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit', 'Aenean eget neque feugiat sem porta lobortis.', 'Sed molestie mantenimiento nunc sagittis, tincidunt tortor eget tristique massa.', 'Proin imperdiet velit eu bibendum volutpat.', 'Cras ullamcorper quam non urna  mensual vestibulum gravida', 'Maecenas semper ante in placerat tristique']
```

We then convert list of tuples to list of string and iterate and search for words in above list of texts. You can tailor this to your needs.  This is to provide an idea of solution.

```
>>> for z in [ [y[0] for y in x] for x in keywords ]:
...   for w in z:
...     for s in sents:
...       if w in s:
...         print(f"found '{w}' in '{s}'")
... 
found 'tarifa' in 'Lorem tarifa ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit'
found 'mantenimiento' in 'Sed molestie mantenimiento nunc sagittis, tincidunt tortor eget tristique massa.'
found 'mensual' in 'Cras ullamcorper quam non urna  mensual vestibulum gravida'
```

Comment: How about `for i, [v] in enumerate(x)`? Reinventing `enumerate` is rather surprising for someone with your reputation...

Comment: @KellyBundy - I'm doing JS from quite sometime and  its well past midnight ,  my brain is not awake. :-)  thanks for reminding.  I've adjusted answer.

Comment: Ah, ok, yeah, that's not healthy. And staying up late isn't good, either. Just in case you missed it: my version doesn't need that extra `y`. (It should work but I haven't tested it, as all those `>>>` and `...` are really inconvenient to remove, especially on a phone...).

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm new to python; I mean I need to save the words as variables and then use them as keywords to filter text in a dataframe. So the first list contains keywords that are used to find a specific text, the second list filters another and so on. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @feruciform -  I think I get it. It may help to put more details in ur question and also provide part of dataframe. For your case you dont need to store in variables. All you need to do is covert tuples to list of strings and iterate through each list item and look if any string matches for text in dataframe. I've adjusted answer with  a sample.

Comment: @Anil_M You are right, I will ask a new question with more context  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72667576/filtering-text-from-dataframe-based-on-keywords-in-a-list), thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -1):

```
 kw =[(' tarifa '),  (' mantenimiento '),  (' mensual ')]

 kw1 = kw[1]

 kw2 = kw[0]

 print(kw2)

output: tarifa
```

You seemed new to python, so I would make it easier for you, please use the index function by sorting out the specific index number of the list your want to give a new variable. try out my examples and removed the commas you used inside the list it will create an error when you run it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).