# Filtering text from dataframe based on keywords in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, variables

I have a list of lists, each sublist of the list contains keywords to filter text from a dataframe.

```
keywords = [[('tarifa',), ('mantenimiento',), ('mensual',)],  
[('tasa',), ('anual',)],    
[('seguro',), ('bancaria',)],  
[('seguro',), ('generales',)],  
[('mi salud',), ('unific',)]]
```

I used to filter by typing the keywords manually like this:

```
#for sublist 1:
kw_s = kw_df[kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains('tarifa') & kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains('mantenimiento') & kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains('mensual')]
#for sublist 2:
kw_s = kw_df[kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains('seguro') & kw_df['transaction_description'].str.contains('generales')]
```

Now I must filter according to the keywords configured in a mysql table. So, I save the keywords in a list of lists, but I don't know how to extract the keywords by sublist to filter the dataframe.

Any idea how I could do it?

Here an example of the dataframe

```
user_id reg_id    date                           transaction_description          value
kw_df = [[5,  56,  Timestamp('2022-01-29 00:00:00'),  'pac c.misalud conv. unificado',  12320.0],
[5,  57,  Timestamp('2021-12-19 00:00:00'),  'cargo seguro proteccion bancaria',  31222.0], 
[5,  60,  Timestamp('2021-04-06 00:00:00'),  'pac sura cia seguros generales',  8657.0],
[5,  178,  Timestamp('2022-03-21 00:00:00'),  'cargo seguro proteccion bancaria',  31222.0], 
[5,  179,  Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'),  'pac c.misalud conv. unificado',  12320.0], 
[5,  182,  Timestamp('2022-03-15 00:00:00'),  'pac sura cia seguros generales',  8657.0],
[5,  189,  Timestamp('2022-04-21 00:00:00'),  'cargo seguro proteccion bancaria',  31222.0],
[5,  190,  Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'),  'pac c.misalud conv. unificado',  12320.0],
[5,  193,  Timestamp('2022-04-15 00:00:00'),  'pac sura cia seguros generales',  8657.0],
[5,  206,  Timestamp('2022-05-21 00:00:00'),  'cargo seguro proteccion bancaria',  31222.0],
[5,  256,  Timestamp('2022-06-17 00:00:00'),  'cargo seguro proteccion bancaria',  40222.0]]
```

Comment: Do you want to filter by *all* of the keywords in each sublist, or *any* of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to filter a DataFrame by a volatile subset of words?

### Dummy data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = ['transaction_description', 'value']
data = [
    ['pac c.misalud conv. unificado', 12320.0],
    ['cargo seguro proteccion bancaria', 31222.0], 
    ['pac sura cia seguros generales', 8657.0],
    ['cargo seguro proteccion bancaria', 31222.0], 
    ['pac c.misalud conv. unificado', 12320.0], 
    ['pac sura cia seguros generales', 8657.0],
    ['cargo seguro proteccion bancaria', 31222.0],
    ['pac c.misalud conv. unificado', 12320.0],
    ['pac sura cia seguros generales', 8657.0],
    ['cargo seguro proteccion bancaria', 31222.0],
    ['cargo seguro proteccion bancaria', 40222.0]]

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

keywords = [
    [('tarifa',), ('mantenimiento',), ('mensual',)], 
    [('tasa',), ('anual',)],    
    [('seguro',), ('bancaria',)],  
    [('seguro',), ('generales',)],  
    [('mi salud',), ('unific',)]]
```

### Solving

I will use a structure where the words of the sublists are arranged in columns, or to be precise, each word is placed in the list as the only element of a tuple.

Let's vectorize `str.__contains__` to make the `str1 in str2` code applicable to arrays:

```py
contains = np.vectorize(str.__contains__)
```

Now, I'll test this function on `df["transaction_description"]` and the 4th set of keywords `[('seguro',), ('generales',)]` for example:

```py
desc = df['transaction_description']
contains(desc, keywords[3])
```

In this case, we get the following result:

```py
array([[False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False]])
```

Now, to see if all words of this subset can be found in a description, we apply the method `all` along the first index of the previous matrix:

```py
df[contains(desc, keywords[3]).all(axis=0)]
```

And we obtain these filtered data:

```
          transaction_description   value
2  pac sura cia seguros generales  8657.0
5  pac sura cia seguros generales  8657.0
8  pac sura cia seguros generales  8657.0
```

### Long story short

```py
contains = np.vectorize(str.__contains__)
desc = df['transaction_description']
contain_all = lambda words: df[contains(desc, words).all(axis=0)]
```

[image: the code and its output]